# Displaying all images from a WordPress post (including media library)

Tags: posts, images

With this function, I'm getting only those images that I uploaded using the upload button in the post section. But, if I add an image from the media library in a post, it's not showing. I want to show all the images from the post.

```
$attachments = get_children(array(
          'post_parent' => $post->ID,
          'post_status' => 'inherit',
          'post_type' => 'attachment',
          'post_mime_type' => 'image',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));

          foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
            $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full');
           
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot use attachments for obvious reasons, an image can be attached to one post/page only, it does not have to be attached, at all, in order to be displayed as part of your post/page. Where all  tags can be found? In a content of post/page. We can use `the_content` hook to have access to those tags. Add this code to `functions.php` of your theme (preferably child theme):

```
function fpw_show_images( $content ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['images'] ) ) {
        preg_match_all( "/<img[^>]+\>/i", $content, $matches );
        $numberOfImages = count( $matches[0] );
        if ( 0 == $numberOfImages ) {
            $out = '<h3>No images</h3>';
        } else {
            $out = '<h3>Number of images: ' . $numberOfImages . '</h3>';
            $out .= '<table style="width:100%">';
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $matches[0] as $img ) {
                if ( 0 == $i )
                    $out .= '<tr>';
                $out .=  '<td style="width:25%">' . $img . '</td>';
                $i++;
                if ( 4 == $i ) {
                    $i = 0;
                    $out .= '</tr>';
                }
            }
            if ( 0 < $i )
                $out .= '</tr>'; 
            $out .= '</table>'; 
        }
        return $out;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'fpw_show_images' );
```

We do not want to add extracted images to the content. It would be redundant, and it will display them to any viewer. Please look at the first `if` block of the code above. It will be executed, if post/page `url` has the parameter `images` added to it:

```
.../?images
```

To detect a presence of this parameter we have to define it, first. For this we will create another filter. Add this code to `functions.php` of your theme:

```
function fpw_images_parameter( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'images';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'fpw_images_parameter' );
```

If the parameter `images` is being used then we will create, and return the new content. The extraction of all `<img>` tags is done by one statement of `fpw_show_images` function:

```
preg_match_all( "/<img[^>]+\>/i", $content, $matches );
```

which will, conveniently, create two dimensional array holding all `img` tags. The rest is just a presentation.